# getting error Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, react-final-form, final-form

I am getting this error

```
**Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set.**
```

I am using `multiselect dropdown` in semantic ui react. when I run my application getting error

**Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set.**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-field-56zpm

```
<RFField
              component={SingleSelectAutoComplete}
              label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"
              name="dropdown"
            />
```

[image]

API

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable-multiple

Comment: The problem is that `RFField` is passing in `props.input.value` an object, while it should be an array of objects. If you can make the default value of `RFField` to an array of objects, then it's fixed.

Comment: how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Idk, I'm not familiar with `react-final-form` or `semantic-ui`. I know what is causing the error, but now how these packages work. If someone that is familiar come to this question, maybe know the problem will help to solve the issue.

Comment: The error itself is shouting the problem.

Comment: Second: __Dropdown `value` must be an **array** when `multiple` is set. Received type: **[object String]**__, yes you passed an array but it was an object with string as value. it must be array of strings

Comment: how to resolve this error

Comment: Do you want it to enable multiple selection or not?

Comment: actully one selection I already added contion

Comment: i already added one condition in onchange .It always selects one item using chip

Comment: any idea ...??  how to resolve

Comment: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors in the console are pretty clear about what you need to change.

Looking at the first message:

> Dropdown prop "value" is auto controlled. Specify either defaultValue or value, but not both.

Since you are using a form manager (react-final-form), the field values are being managed by the Form component. So you should remove the `defaultValue` prop from the Dropdown component:

```
      <Dropdown
        ...
        selection
        options={data}
        defaultValue={[]} // remove this prop
```

The second error:

> Dropdown `value` must be an array when `multiple` is set. Received type: `[object String]`.

I think react-final-form initializes unknown values as an empty string. So you should define the "dropdown" value as an empty array in the `initialValues` prop of the Form:

```
      <RFFORM
        initialValues={{
          dropdown: [],
        }}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
```

Here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-gould-fepxk